# React Router - reset state when switching route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to reset state to its' initial value when a Route is switched?

In this component I'm using `useContext()` to get state `searchedMovie`. I want to have it the default value the first time `MoviePage` component is rendered. However, now its' value is passed from parent component instead

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Topbar from '../Header/Topbar';
import MovieContent from '../Pages/MovieContent';
import Catalog from '../Catalog/Catalog';
import { MoviesContext } from "../../services/context";
import './Pages.scss';

const MoviePage = (props: any) => {

  const { searchedMovie } = useContext(MoviesContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Topbar></Topbar>
      {searchedMovie === '' ? <MovieContent></MovieContent> : <Catalog></Catalog>}
    </>
  );
}

export default MoviePage;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should include the relevant code you want "fixed", i.e. the `MoviesContext` code that you want `searchMovie` value reset, and your routing code & logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use React's useState hook for this logic so it will have the initial value when component is rendered :

```
const [ searchedMovie , setSearchedMovie ] = React.useState("");
```

Otherwise you must change the state in a react useEffect hook like this :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 // your logic to change the searchedMovie state
} , [] )
```

The useEffect hook will always run and change the state when component mounts or it's props or state changes .